# Changing the value of each string property in an object

Tags: c#

I have an object that contains a number of child objects, with each of the children objects having a varying number of string properties.

I want to write a method that allows me to input a single parent object which will iterate through every string property in each child object and trim the whitespace from the property contents.

For visualisation:

```
public class Parent
{
    Child1 child1 { get; set;}
    Child2 child2 { get; set;}
    Child3 child3 { get; set;}
}

public class Child1 (Child2 and Child3 classes are similar)
{
    string X { get; set; }
    string Y { get; set; }
    string Z { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following code, which creates a list of properties in the parent class, then iterates through each of them and finds the child properties which are strings, and then operates on them. But for some reason this does not seem to have any effect on the values of the properties.

```
private Parent ReduceWhitespaceAndTrimInstruction(Parent p)
{
    var parentProperties = p.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach(var properties in parentProperties)
    {
        var stringProperties = p.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));

        foreach(var stringProperty in stringProperties)
        {
            string currentValue = (string)stringProperty.GetValue(instruction, null);

            stringProperty.SetValue(p, currentValue.ToString().Trim(), null);
        }
    }
    return instruction;
}
```

Edit: Forgot to mention. The problem seems to step from the inner `foreach`, the outer foreach finds each property, but finding the properties that only are strings seems to work incorrectly.

Edit: Updated Method

```
private Parent ReduceAndTrim(Parent parent)
        {
            var parentProperties = parent.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var property in parentProperties)
            {
                var child = property.GetValue(parent);
                var stringProperties = child.GetType().GetProperties()
                    .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string));

                foreach (var stringProperty in stringProperties)
                {
                    string currentValue = (string) stringProperty.GetValue(child, null);
                    stringProperty.SetValue(child, currentValue.ToString().Trim(), null);
                }
            }

            return parent;
        }
```

Comment: In the `Where` statement, don't you want to search for objects of type `Child1` there?

Comment: Correct yes, how would I go about iterating through the properties of each child object found in parent?

Comment: I think the error is you are using `p` there but you want `var stringProperties = properties .GetType().Get.....`

Comment: Why don't you give the Child object a function that would give you a list of all their string and so the parent would implement a function that would concatenate the lists of all its children. (Or simply have a List of Children and each Children has a list of Child? )

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, `properties.GetType()` will give `typeof(PropertyInfo)` and that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: What is the value of `instruction` and `child` in your foreach ? Also, `p` in your `.Where` is a bit wonky.  The LINQ should be something more like `var stringProperties = p.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string));`

Answer (score 1):

Your `stringProperties` enumerable contains no items, because you're asking the `Parent` type to give you all properties of type `string` - there are none.

```
var stringProperties = p.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));
```

Note that `p` is of type `Parent`, so `p.GetType()` yields `typeof(Parent)`.

You need to get each property value (each `Child` instance) of `Parent`'s instance instead:

```
var parentProperties = p.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var property in parentProperties)
{    
    var child = property.GetValue(p);
    var stringProperties = child.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));

    // etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the OP with a new method. Can you take a look and see if it is correct?

Comment: @JakeMangan, did you try it yourself? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The GetProperties method only returns the **public** properties of your type. If you change the property of your Parent class to the following, you should be able to move forward:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child1 Child1 { get; set; }
    public Child2 Child2 { get; set; }
    public Child3 Child3 { get; set; }
}
```

But this line of code will still return null because there is no property of "parent" in your child classes:

```
var child = property.GetValue(parent);
```

I hope it helped :D